# slideshow with page numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have created slideshow. I want to add some description with page numbers.
I was trying to add function sliderText() to get result - "Image 1 of 7" etc.

I don't know what is wrong here. Can somebody give me some hints?

Thank you in advance, 
Megi

```js
var img_index = 0;
var imgs = [
  "assets/1.jpg",
  "assets/2.jpg",
  "assets/3.jpg",
  "assets/4.jpg",
  "assets/5.jpg",
  "assets/6.jpg",
  "assets/7.jpg"

];


function findNextImage(isPrev) {
  switch (true) {
    case !!(isPrev && imgs[img_index + 1]):
      img_index += 1
      return imgs[img_index]

    case !!imgs[img_index + 1]:
      img_index += 1
      return imgs[img_index]

    default:
      img_index = 0
      return imgs[img_index]

  }

  sliderText()
}



function checkKey(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '39') {
    document.getElementById("images").src = findNextImage();
    
  } else if (event.keyCode == '37') {
    document.getElementById("images").src = findNextImage(true);
  }

}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;





function sliderText() {
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow_text");
  var imageNumber = img_index + 1;
  text.innerHTML = "image " + imageNumber + " of " + imgs.length;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<h1 class="slideshow_text">Image 1 of 7</h1>
<img id="images" src="assets/1.jpg" />


<body>

</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some modifications to improve code quality**

I removed `findNextImage` which was not a pure function and introduced `findNextImageIndex` instead: `findNextImageIndex` neither accesses nor modifies any external variables and is thus easier to read. `sliderText` takes `imgIndex` as an argument so that you can easily see what parameters it needs to set the text.

**Further suggestions**

Consider moving the pre-set values `Image 1 of 7` and `"assets/1.jpg"` from HTML to JavaScript as well. Initialize the slider with `"assets/1.jpg"` taken from the array and call `sliderText(state.imgIndex);` once initially.

Please notice that I moved the slide show HTML inside the `<body>` to make it valid HTML.

**Modified code**

```js
var state = {
  imgIndex: 0
};
var imgs = [
  "assets/1.jpg",
  "assets/2.jpg",
  "assets/3.jpg",
  "assets/4.jpg",
  "assets/5.jpg",
  "assets/6.jpg",
  "assets/7.jpg"
];

function findNextImageIndex(imgIndex, isPrev) {
  if(isPrev) {
    if(imgIndex <= 0) {
      return imgs.length - 1;
    } else {
      return imgIndex - 1;
    }
  } else {
    if(imgIndex >= imgs.length - 1) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return imgIndex + 1;
    }
  }
}

function sliderText(imgIndex) {
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow_text")[0];
  var imageNumber = imgIndex + 1;
  text.innerHTML = "image " + imageNumber + " of " + imgs.length;
}

function goToNextImage(isPrev) {
  state.imgIndex = findNextImageIndex(state.imgIndex, isPrev);
  document.getElementById("images").src = imgs[state.imgIndex];
  sliderText(state.imgIndex);
}

function checkKey(event) {
  switch(event.keyCode) {
    case 37: goToNextImage(true); break;
    case 39: goToNextImage(false); break;
  }
}

document.onkeydown = checkKey;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="slideshow_text">Image 1 of 7</h1>
  <img id="images" src="assets/1.jpg" />
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```